# How to invoke 'info make' with ~/path/to/make.info

Tags: make, gnu, info

If I type in bash `info make` I get the hint to refer to the Info file make.info which is made from Texinfo source file make.texi.

Is there a short way for instead of always typing `info -f ~/path/to/make.info`?

I just want to type `info make` to refer to this file.

Comment: So the basic idea is this: a script called info, that searches for a file matching the first argument plus the extension .info?

Comment: @grooveplex: Yes, I had this idea also, as well as writing a bash function. But my intention is just to redirect `info` only for this file, because only in this case I have a newer file than the command `info` is suggesting. Is there no other way to accomplish this?

Comment: There sure is. Add to `.bash_profile`: `alias info-make="info -f ~/path/to/make.info"`. Then execute `source .bash_profile` and type `info-make`.

Comment: @grooveplex: Of course, but I would like to type `info make` instead of `info-make`, because I don't want to rember always how many extra commands I made.

Comment: I wrote in my ~/.bashrc

Comment: Now execute `source .bashrc`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't fast enough. I wrote in my ~/.bashrc `info () {
 if [ "$1" = "make" ]
 then
  info -f ~/path/to/make.info
 else
  info $1
 fi
}`

Then I sourced my bashrc and typed `info make`.
But this doesn't work.

Comment: This only kills my screen window.

Comment: And if I work on another tty without screen, it's also like hitting ctrl+d.

Comment: At least I found a solution without coding or an entry in any rc files.
I went to the directory where my make.info file is stored and executed:

`gzip -c make.info > make.info.gz` and then `sudo cp make.info.gz /usr/share/info` Thank you for your efforts.